# Taking the first records for each group in pandas dataframe and putting 0 in other records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
s = {'id': [243,243, 243, 243,443,443,443],
 'st': [1,3,5,9,2,6,7],
 'value':[2.4, 3.8, 3.7, 5.6, 1.2, 0.2, 2.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
```

which looks like this:

```
    id  st  value
0  243   1    2.4
1  243   3    3.8
2  243   5    3.7
3  243   9    5.6
4  443   2    1.2
5  443   6    0.2
6  443   7    2.1
```

I want to put 0 as `value` for all the records except of the first records for each `id` . My expected output is:

```
    id  st  value
0  243   1    2.4
1  243   3    0
2  243   5    0
3  243   9    0
4  443   2    1.2
5  443   6    0
6  443   7    0
```

How can I do this with a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for set values by mask with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.loc[df['id'].duplicated(), 'value'] = 0
```

Or:

```
df['value'] = np.where(df['id'].duplicated(), 0, df['value'])
print (df)
    id  st  value
0  243   1    2.4
1  243   3    0.0
2  243   5    0.0
3  243   9    0.0
4  443   2    1.2
5  443   6    0.0
6  443   7    0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way checking for duplicates in `id` and multiplying the `boolean` result by `value`:

```
df['value'] = (~df.id.duplicated('first')).mul(df.value)

    id  st  value
0  243   1    2.4
1  243   3    0.0
2  243   5    0.0
3  243   9    0.0
4  443   2    1.2
5  443   6    0.0
6  443   7    0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is:

```
df.loc[df.id.eq(df.id.shift()),'value']=0
print(df)
```

---

```
    id  st  value
0  243   1    2.4
1  243   3    0.0
2  243   5    0.0
3  243   9    0.0
4  443   2    1.2
5  443   6    0.0
6  443   7    0.0
```